# Javascript findIndex for duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

JavaScript `findIndex` returns the very first finded index in case of duplicate values

```js
const arr = [{a: 10, b: 20, c: 30},{a: 15, b: 25, c: 32},{a: 10, b: 23, c: 350}]
const index = arr.findIndex(m => m.a === 10)
console.log(index);
```

The above code will only return 0 index.

What should I do to get index 2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) of the array like this:

```js
const arr = [{a: 10, b: 20, c: 30},{a: 15, b: 25, c: 32},{a: 10, b: 23, c: 350}]
const indices = [...arr.keys()].filter(i => arr[i].a === 10)
console.log(indices)
```

Or, just use a `for` loop

```js
const arr = [{a: 10, b: 20, c: 30},{a: 15, b: 25, c: 32},{a: 10, b: 23, c: 350}]
const output = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].a === 10)
    output.push(i)
}

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.reduce((result, current, index) => {
   return result.concat(current.a == 10 ? [index]: [])
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and "[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)" before answering a question. Please add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use of `Array.reduce` to loop on your arr and returns every indexes

**Single line** :

```js
const arr = [{
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  c: 30,
}, {
  a: 15,
  b: 25,
  c: 32,
}, {
  a: 10,
  b: 23,
  c: 350,
}]

// Value to check for
const v = 10;

// we loop on every entry of the arr
// we start with an empty array and look if the entries
// contains the value 10, if they do, we push the index of the
// entry in the array that was empty
//
// we do that for every entry of arr, when we treat all, we return
// the list of matching entries
const idx = arr.reduce((tmp, x, xi) => (x.a === v ? [...tmp, xi] : tmp), []);

console.log(idx);
```

---

**Explained** :

```js
const arr = [{
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  c: 30,
}, {
  a: 15,
  b: 25,
  c: 32,
}, {
  a: 10,
  b: 23,
  c: 350,
}]

const valToCheck = 10;

const indexes = arr.reduce((tmp, x, xi) => {
  if (x.a === valToCheck) {
    tmp.push(xi);
  }

  return tmp;
}, []);

console.log(indexes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `filter`:

```js
const arr = [{a: 10, b: 20, c: 30},{a: 15, b: 25, c: 32},{a: 10, b: 23, c: 350}];
const res = arr.map(({ a }, i) => a == 10 ? i : "").filter(String);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the indices of the found items and filter only valid indices.

```js
const
    array = [{ a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 }, { a: 15, b: 25, c: 32 }, { a: 10, b: 23, c: 350 }],
    indices = array
        .map((m, i) => m.a === 10 ? i : -1)
        .filter(i => i != -1);

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through array and push matching index in new array.

```
const arr = [{a: 10, b: 20, c: 30},{a: 15, b: 25, c: 32},{a: 10, b: 23, c: 350}]
let p = []
arr.forEach((ele,index)=> ele.a===10 ? p.push(index) : '')
console.log(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```js
const arr = [{a: 10, b: 20, c: 30},{a: 15, b: 25, c: 32},{a: 10, b: 23, c: 350}];

const indices = arr.map((x, index) => {
 if (x.a === 10) {
  return index;
 }
})
.filter(x => x !== undefined);

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function which works directly with Array, add this in `Array.prototype`

```js
Array.prototype.findAllIndexes = function(iteratee){
    var resultArray = [];
    this.forEach(function(element) {
        var validated = iteratee.call(this, element);
        if(validated) {
            resultArray.push(element);
        }
    });
    return resultArray;
}
```

Then you can use it anywher you want with array object

*(please handle your corner cases based od data type you use)*

```js
const arr = [{a: 10, b: 20, c: 30},{a: 15, b: 25, c: 32},{a: 10, b: 23, c: 350}]
const index = arr.findAllIndexes(m => m.a === 10)
console.log(index);
```

> You can use some helper libraries to this kind of stuff like `lodash.js`, you can include them in your project.